# My recursive solution in Python is appending and replacing all current items in answer list with the current list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to implement a Python solution to the programming question
of finding all subsets in an integer array. I should return an array
that contains all subsets of the integer array with no duplicates and
sorted.

```
def subsetHelper(cur_set, index, A, ans):
    if index >= len(A):
        print "appending ", cur_set
        ans.append(cur_set)
        print "ans: ", ans
        return
    # don't include current number
    subsetHelper(cur_set, index+1, A, ans)

    # include current number
    cur_set.append(A[index])
    subsetHelper(cur_set, index+1, A, ans)
    cur_set.pop()

def subsets(A):
    A.sort()
    ans = []
    cur_set = []
    # dont include current number
    subsetHelper(cur_set, 0, A, ans)
    return ans
```

Implementing this same logic in C++ results in the correct return value. However when I do this in Python all I get are a collection of empty lists at the very end, while during iteration it's copying the same current list to all items in the list, even though the print out shows its appending the correct subset each time. Why is this happening? Here is the output:

```
print subsets([1,2,3])
appending  []
ans:  [[]]
appending  [3]
ans:  [[3], [3]]
appending  [2]
ans:  [[2], [2], [2]]
appending  [2, 3]
ans:  [[2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3], [2, 3]]
appending  [1]
ans:  [[1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
appending  [1, 3]
ans:  [[1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3], [1, 3]]
appending  [1, 2]
ans:  [[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
appending  [1, 2, 3]
ans:  [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Comment: I don't really understand why you are making this a class. You have no instance attributes other than methods which pass around the same parameters. Anyway, the problem is that you are passing around the same list, not making copies. That is, you are building up a list of references to the same list! Every time you append `cur_list` it's the same list object. That is why when you finally pop everythin when every recursive call to subsetHelper reaches the last line, you end up with a list of empty lists.

Comment: Could you please the full code you use the get this output ? (i.e. how you are calling `Solution`).

Comment: Don't use this, but this works (as does [itertools](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html)) to test your implementation: `def subsets(L): return sorted([[L[j] for j in range(len(L)) if 1 << j & i] for i in range(2**len(L))])` :)

Comment: Sorry guys I completely screwed up my post. the new edit shows what my original problem was supposed to look like. Also I am completely aware of the fact that having the Solution class is pointless, I was just copying the code I wrote on a console in a prep website called http://www.interviewbit.com, where the boilerplate code has the solution method you're supposed to implement inside of a Solution class. I apologize for all of these mistakes and I'll try to proofread my post in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 2 problem here: the problem first is that you `ans.extend` instead of `ans.append`, once change that we get the second problem which is empty list at the end and the reason is that append only add to the list `ans` a reference to `cur_set` which you end up removing all element in the course of the recursion so you end up with several references to the same list that is empty at the end, to fix this you only need to append a copy of the current content of the list with `list(cur_set)` for instance.

Also there is no reason to make this a class

```
def subsetHelper(cur_set, index, A, ans):
    if index >= len(A):
        print "appending ", cur_set
        ans.append(list(cur_set))  # <--- here was the problem
        print "ans: ", ans
        return
    # don't include current number
    subsetHelper(cur_set, index+1, A, ans)

    # include current number
    cur_set.append(A[index])
    self.subsetHelper(cur_set, index+1, A, ans)
    cur_set.pop()

def subsets(A):
    A.sort()
    ans = []
    cur_set = []
    # dont include current number
    subsetHelper(cur_set, 0, A, ans)
    return ans
```

test

```
>>> subsets([1,2,3])
appending  []
ans:  [[]]
appending  [3]
ans:  [[], [3]]
appending  [2]
ans:  [[], [3], [2]]
appending  [2, 3]
ans:  [[], [3], [2], [2, 3]]
appending  [1]
ans:  [[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1]]
appending  [1, 3]
ans:  [[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3]]
appending  [1, 2]
ans:  [[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2]]
appending  [1, 2, 3]
ans:  [[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
[[], [3], [2], [2, 3], [1], [1, 3], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3]]
>>>
```

Comment: This is it! as well as the other comments. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're re-using the cur_set list object between calls so even after `cur_set` has been added to `ans`, futures calls to `susetHelper` still modify the list, specifically future calls to `cur_set.pop()` empty the list. You can solve this problem by storing a copy of `cur_set` instead of the exact object.

```
def subsetHelper(cur_set, index, A, ans):
    if index >= len(A):
        print "appending ", cur_set
        ans.append(cur_set[:])
        print "ans: ", ans
        return
    # don't include current number
    subsetHelper(cur_set, index+1, A, ans)

    # include current number
    cur_set.append(A[index])
    subsetHelper(cur_set, index+1, A, ans)
    cur_set.pop()

def subsets(A):
    A.sort()
    ans = []
    cur_set = []
    # dont include current number
    subsetHelper(cur_set, 0, A, ans)
    return ans

print subsets([12, 13])
```

Not that you're mixing state based oop and functional programing styles here. There is nothing wrong with that in principle, but debugging state based recursion can be very frustrating. If this is a learning exercise, I'd suggest you try to solve this problem in a purely functional way first (recursive way) then do it again in a purely state based way. Doing it both ways will give you a better understanding of the problem.